# Web Service creation in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, web-services, tomcat

I am using eclipse Luna,tomcat 7 and axis 1.6. I am creating webservice for spring mvc controller. Here is my code

```
 package com.hp.hpl.ress.phoenix.web;
    import com.hp.hpl.ress.phoenix.service.*;
    import com.hp.hpl.ress.phoenix.domain.*;
    import com.hp.hpl.ress.phoenix.flex.service.HomeViewService;
    import com.hp.hpl.ress.phoenix.flex.service.NotificationFacade;
    import com.hp.hpl.ress.phoenix.flex.vo.UserVO;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.TimeZone;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    @Controller
    public class PhoenixController {
    protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    @Autowired
    private InstallationService installationService;
    @Autowired
    private HomeViewService homeViewService;
    @RequestMapping("/home.htm")
    public ModelAndView showHomePage() {
    List<Installation> allInstallations =    

    installationService.getAllInstallations();
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("home");
    mav.addObject("pageName", "Home Page");
    mav.addObject("installations", allInstallations);
    return mav;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/viewInstallation.htm")
    public ModelAndView viewInstallation(@RequestParam("installationId") String 

    installationId) {
    logger.debug("Started to render installation view: " + new Date());
    Installation installation =  

    installationService.getInstallation(Integer.parseInt(installationId));
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("viewInstallationDetail");
    mav.addObject("pageName", "Installation detail");
    mav.addObject("installation", installation);
    logger.debug("Finished rendering installation view: " + new Date());
    return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/viewZone.htm")
    public ModelAndView viewZone(@RequestParam("zoneId") String zoneId) {
    logger.debug("Started to render zone view: " + new Date());
    Zone zone = installationService.getZone(Integer.parseInt(zoneId));
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("viewZoneDetail");
    mav.addObject("pageName", "Zone detail");
    mav.addObject("zone", zone);
    logger.debug("Finished rendering zone view: " + new Date());
    return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/viewSensor.htm")
    public ModelAndView viewSensor(@RequestParam("sensorId") String sensorId) {
    logger.debug("Started to render sensor view: " + new Date());
    Sensor sensor = installationService.getSensor(Integer.parseInt(sensorId));
    Calendar start =  

    Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(sensor.getTimeZone()));
    start.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    start.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    start.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Calendar end = (GregorianCalendar)start.clone();
    end.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    List<SensorReading> readings = 

    installationService.getRangeOfReadings(sensor, start, end);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("viewSensorDetail");
    mav.addObject("pageName", "Installation details");
    mav.addObject("sensor", sensor);
    mav.addObject("readings", readings);
    logger.debug("Finished rendering sensor view: " + new Date());
    return mav;
    }


    @RequestMapping("/homeSummary.htm")
    public ModelAndView homeSummary() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("viewHomeSummary");
        //yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm

    UserVO userSummary = homeViewService.getUserSummary(1, "2010/08/01 00:00",  

    3);
    mav.addObject("UserSummary", userSummary);
    return mav;
    }
    public void setInstallationService(InstallationService installationService)    

    {
        this.installationService = installationService;
    }

    }
```

When i try to create web service for this controller using eclipse i am getting Selection must be WSDL Error.. I tried many times. i have added axis 2 in project facets also,

Comment: I think it's easier if you expose your methods with spring without axis

Comment: Expose methods with spring means?? i didnt get. could you please elaborate?

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 1):

I had your same problem and i used this solution. Using spring controller as services in this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "services/utente/getUtenteByUsername", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getUtenteDaUsername( @RequestParam("username") String username, Model model) {

            utente = utenteBo.findByUsername(username);

            String jsonResult = "";

            if (utente != null) {

                    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
                    Gson gson = builder.create();

                    jsonResult = gson.toJson(utente);

                    return jsonResult;
            } 
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I've used json to send the response. 
Hope can helps you.

Comment: Sorry i cant modify my code. Should i return json instead of model and view?

Comment: u have just to add @responseBody and return a json

Comment: do i need to add services in Request mapping?

Comment: i don't know your project settings...in my project i use a file xml with the function of a dispatcher where i mapping the servlets and where its specified where to get the controllers;

<context:component-scan base-package="DSTAProject.servlet.controller" />

Comment: Thanks.. but my question is when i try to create webService for this controller i am getting selection must be wsdl error

Comment: Using axis it's really hard. Good Luck

Comment: ok.. then how can i create web service for controller? and i am using eclipse  id to implement web service and i am not hard coding anything

Comment: You seen my code? That it's already a webservice... you can call the url mapped and get a json in the response. A webservice expose methods, and my code expose a method.

Comment: ok.. i will add services in my Request mapping annoation. then can i  write a standalone project to test web service?